# Placing a small object at the beggining of memory block

Tags: object, c++14

I need to store a object describing the memory details of a memory block allocated by sbrk(), at the beggining of the memory block itself.
for example:

```
metaData det();
void* alloc = sbrk(sizeof(det)+50000);
//a code piece to locate det at the beggining of alocate.
```

I am not allowed to use placement new, And not allowed to allocate memory using new/malloc etc.
I know that simply assigning it to the memory block would cause undefined behaviour.
I was thinking about using memcpy (i think that can cause problems as det is not dynamicly allocated).
Could assigning a pointer to the object at the beginning work (only if theres no other choise), or memcpy?
thanks.

Comment: `metaData det();` declares a *function*, that takes no arguments and return a `metaData` object by value.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not allowed to use placement new

Placement new is the only way to place an object in an existing block of memory.

> **[intro.object]** An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created

- You cannot make a definition to refer to an existing memory region, so that's out.
- There's no union, so that's also out.
- A temporary object cannot be created in an existing block of memory, so that's also out.

The only remaining way is with a new expression, and of  those, only placement new can refer to an existing block of memory.

So you are out of luck as far as the C++ standard goes.

However the same problem exists with `malloc`. There are tons of code out there that use `malloc` without bothering to use placement new. Such code just casts the result of `malloc` to the target type and proceeds from there. This method works in practice, and there is no sign of it being ever broken.

```
metaData *det = static_cast<metaData *>(alloc);
```

On an unrelated note, `metaData det();` declares a function, and `sizeof` is not applicable to functions.